# Difference between Futures.addCallBack() and Futures.transform() in Google Guava Concurrency

Tags: java, asynchronous, concurrency, guava

What is the difference between `Futures.addCallBack()` and `Futures.transform()` in [Google Guava Concurrency](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/).

**As per the documentation:**

**[Futures.addCallBack()](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/util/concurrent/Futures.html#addCallback%28com.google.common.util.concurrent.ListenableFuture,%20com.google.common.util.concurrent.FutureCallback%29):**
`addCallback(ListenableFuture<V> future, FutureCallback<? super V> callback)` Registers separate success and failure callbacks to be run when the Future's computation is complete or, if the computation is already complete, immediately.

**[Futures.transform()](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/util/concurrent/Futures.html#transform%28com.google.common.util.concurrent.ListenableFuture,%20com.google.common.util.concurrent.AsyncFunction%29):**
`transform(ListenableFuture<I> input, AsyncFunction<? super I,? extends O> function)` Returns a new ListenableFuture whose result is asynchronously derived from the result of the given Future.

As per my understanding `addCallback()` will register success or failure callback when asynchronous processing is completed. In this case we can handle the out put based on success or failure conditions (example: logging, flow control..etc). and `transform()` only return the Asynchronous object back. So difference is only Callback?.

1. whether my understanding is correct?
2. Which is the best one to use with asynchronous processing?
3. If I need to call multiple asynchronous methods in a sequence, is there any best practice for that?
4. What is the difference between using `AsyncFunction` and `Function` in `transform(ListenableFuture<I> input, Function/AsyncFunction <? super I,? extends O> function)`? (AsyncFunction only used for nested `Futures.transform()`?)

**What I tried:**
I try to write code like below, whether this is a good practice or not.

```
public ListenableFuture<MyObject> doSomething() {
    logger.info( "Entered in dosomething() Method." );  

    ListeningExecutorService executor =
            MoreExecutors.listeningDecorator(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(50));

    ListenableFuture<MyObject> myAsyncObject =
            calculator.calculateSomething(input);
    //internally calculator.calculateSomething() have multiple asynchronous
    // calls and I am using Futures.transform(), without callback.

    Futures.addCallback(myAsyncObject, new FutureCallback<MyObject>() {
        public void onSuccess(MyObject result) {
            logger.info( "Calculation Completed successfully." );
            //TODO: check for success and log it.
        }

        public void onFailure(Throwable thrown) {
            logErrorDetails(thrown);
        }
    }, executor);

    executor.shutdown();

    return myAsyncObject;
}
```

Comment: The difference is in how you use it. Transformations can be piped together whereas normal callbacks are terminating.

Comment: Note that you'll have problems running your callback (in the future) on an executor that you shut down **now** (sequentially with the addition of the callback). You also usually don't want to create a different executor for each invocation of the method.

Answer (score 1):

Well you didn't write the full method signature in your question

- `addCallback` returns nothing
- `transform` returns a future that holds result of the function (if the input succeeded) or the original input's failure (if not). This allows to chain transformations, with a fluent syntax.

I've not used `AsyncFunction`, but I understand they add one level of asynchronicity, ie the result of the `Future` is another `Future`.